# Java Runtime Error for Calculating Area and Volume of Cylinder

Tags: java, error-handling, runtime-error

I have a question. This program is supposed to receive two integers R and L (both between 1 and 1000) and calculate the area and volume of a cylinder. My problem is that I keep getting runtime errors. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int radius = input.nextInt();
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int length = input2.nextInt();

        while ((radius > 1000) || (radius < 1))
        {
            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            radius = input.nextInt();
        }

        while ((length > 1000) || (length < 1))
        {
            input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            length = input2.nextInt();
        }

        double area = (radius * radius) * 3.14159;
        double volume = area * length;

        System.out.printf("%.1f\n", area);
        System.out.printf("%.1f\n", volume);
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at 
    java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862) at 
    java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485) at 
    java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413) at
    Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Comment: What runtime errors? I don't see any.

Comment: Hello Mr. Prokhorov.

So you mean that this program would run and terminate successfully, right?
I'm currently using a grading program that my school uses, and it says that there is a runtime error... More specifically:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
 at Main.main(Main.java:10)

What does this mean? Thank you.

Comment: I mean "you don't show what your errors are." Now you do, but you should've included it from the start.

Comment: You only have one keyboard, therefore, you only need one scanner, so reuse it. Try "length = input.nextInt();" and get rid of the "new Scanner() lines

Comment: What older coder said.  Create a Scanner *once* —which the first line of your program is already doing—and remove all other `new Scanner` statements.

Comment: Please edit your error message into the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling netInt() on input you need to check if it has some input. Also you do not need to reinitialise input and input2 every time. In fact you should use only one input Scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int radius = 0;
    if(input.hasNextInt() ){
        radius = input.nextInt();
    }
    int length = 0;
    //Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    if(input.hasNextInt() ){
        length = input.nextInt();
    }
    while ((radius > 1000) || (radius < 1))
    {
       // input = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(input.hasNextInt() ){
          radius = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    while ((length > 1000) || (length < 1))
    {
        //input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(input.hasNextInt() ){
           length = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    double area = (radius * radius) * 3.14159;
    double volume = area * length;

    System.out.printf("%.1f\n", area);
    System.out.printf("%.1f\n", volume);
  }
}
```